# Hardcode database field limits and valid values in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, field, limit

I am creating a table in MySQL.
What I need is a field that accepts only 10 NUMBERS.
Is there a way to enforce this limitation (and others) on the database level?

Thanks.

Comment: Like, one choice of ten possibilities? If so, ENUM field. Or do you mean exactly ten distinct numerical values? Or do you mean exactly ten digits? Or other? :-)

Comment: I mislead you both with the Caps on NUMBERS. I meant **10 DIGITS**. Thanks, Wiseguy. How do I limit a field like that?

Comment: Does it need to be _exactly_ ten digits, or just no more than ten digits? (I'm wondering if you'd want `ZEROFILL` to make `47` into `0000000047`.)

Comment: Has to be exactly 10 digits and ZEROFILL will/should not be needed.

Comment: In that case I think you'd need to use a trigger, as @Marc B suggested, but to verify that the value is exactly ten digits long. To check length, you could check that `FLOOR(value / 1000000000)` is between 1 and 9 inclusive.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to store multiple values in a single field. It's a recipe for pain/frustration and invariably a sign of bad design. Use a child table to store the values, and enforce the no-more-than-10 at that level. You'd need to [add a trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) to this table to count the number of records present and abort the insert if it's >= 10.